# Mongo linking/referencing: most efficient way? examples?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I'm trying to figure out how to link/reference a document to another document but I'm not finding much information or examples in the docs or other sources. When linking documents, do I have to link by ObjectID or can I use any field? Do I need to pull the field value directly from the originating document or can I pass the same value from anywhere? For example, given a hex string of a UUID object, I want to link 2 documents via a field 'GUID' which contains the uuid1 object:

```
 # What is more efficience/the correct way, option 1 or 2?

 # Option 1
 hexString = '5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47'
 newLinkField = { 'linkToSong' : uuid.UUID( hexString ) }
 db.artists.update( { 'name' : 'Bob Dylan' }, { $set : newLinkField }, upsert = False)

 # Option 2
 hexString = '5d78ad35ea5f11e1a183705681b29c47'
 songGUID = db.songs.find_one({ 'GUID' : uuid.UUID( hexString ) }, {'GUID': 1 });
 newLinkField = { 'linkToSong' : songGUID }
 db.artists.update( { 'name' : 'Bob Dylan' }, { $set : newLinkField }, upsert = False)
```

Also, is this storing actual links or just duplicates of the UUID object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend this 10gen video for understanding linking and embedding, how to use them, and what the tradeoffs are:

http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosv-2011/schema-design-principles-and-practice

To answer your questions: "linking" a document A to a document B simply means putting *some* information in A that allows your application to query for B. Typically, it'd be something like this:

```
// Document A, in collection 'comments':
{ _id: ObjectId('123...'), user: ObjectId('abc...'), text: 'Hi!' }

// Document B, in collection 'users':
{ _id: ObjectId('abc...'), name: 'Jesse' }
```

Document A, my comment, is linked to B, my user profile. Your application can query for A however it wants to (by _id, by user, by text, ...) and then examine its 'user' field, then find my user profile by querying the users collection for that ObjectId.

The field you use to link A to B should probably be unique in B's collection, and it should *definitely* be indexed in B's collection.

Both requirements are always satisfied by any collection's _id field, but they could be satisfied by some other field as well.

Your example 1 is fine. Although you probably have it backwards: songs should have artist ids in them, rather than vice-versa, unless Bob Dylan has only ever written one song.

In example 2, it is unnecessary and costly to find the song before the artist, if you already know how you're going to query for the artist document.

Answer (score -1):

[Mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/) can make references between models just out of the box. But this is really bad thing what you do with document-oriented database. Because you can get problems on scaling you DB and solves based on references decrease performance of noSQL dbs.
Feel free to write all data what you need in one record, for example if you need create record for song you can do it like this:

```
{'title': 'Black and white', 'singer': 'M Jackson', 'album': 'Some album' and etc}
```

dont afraid data overhead, object-oriented DB primarily designed for these things.

Comment: how will you be handling problem of data duplication. for example we have another record {'title': 'Beat It', 'singer': 'M Jackson', 'album': 'Some album' and etc}